# Can an HOA control how a homeowner enters and exits their home?

Tags: united-states, is-x-legal, hoa

Is it illegal for me to exit my bedroom via my first-floor bedroom window?

Is this likely to be against common or standard HOA regulations or rules?

Suppose that the house and land are owned by myself or my family. It is not an emergency situation; I feel like leaving through the window instead of the door. There is no question of this being a commercial building or one which is leased, and I have every right to be present on the property or to enter and exit the building at any time.

Comment: Which state in the USA?

Comment: Michigan, and thanks for the edit Nij :)

Comment: Why don't you read the HOA regulations or rules? We don't know them.

Comment: Or, you could ask whether an HOA *can* prohibit you from exiting via the window.

Comment: The title was appropriate for the question before it was (helpfully) edited. I think this is too uncommon for an HOA to already have rules about and the suggestion that the police would do something about it is still not believable. I'm sure the message was nothing to get curious about.

Comment: Local fire codes may well have a *requirement* for an alternate exit from a  bedroom...